# docker run -v 'pwd':/home ,seemed not working

Tags: docker

It seemes `pwd` not mounted on `/home`. Why?

**What I run:**

```
$docker run -v 'pwd':/home gsl gcc -I /usr/include/  -L /usr/lib / -lgsl -lgslcblas /home/src.bessel.c -o /home/bin/bessel
```

**Got next error:**

> gcc: error: /home/src/bessel.c :no such file or directory

Comment: Please rewrite your description, separating clearly code samples from questions, this is practically unreadable as-is

Comment: $docker run -v 'pwd':/home gsl gcc -I /usr/include/ -L /usr/lib / -lgsl -lgslcblas /home/src/bessel.c -o /home/bin/bessel

Comment: shown, gcc: error: /home/src/bessel.c :no such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

You can mount pwd in a container with :

```sh
docker run -v $PWD:/home
```

or

```sh
docker run -v `pwd`:/home
```

use ` and not '